# I am trying to translate a bullet up when left button is clicked

Tags: c#, monogame

In a minigame I am creating, tanks spawn at the top of the screen and move down towards the player, and the player must click left mouse button to shoot a bullet which should continuously move up until it hits something. Here is my code.

```
private void tankShoot(GameTime gameTime)
{
        if (mouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && prevMouse.LeftButton != ButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            speed.Y = bulletDirY * (bulletSpeed * (float)(gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds));

            bulletPos.Y = bulletPos.Y - speed.Y;
            bulletRec.Y = (int)bulletPos.Y;
        }
}
```

When left button is clicked, the bullet moves one pixel. The player needs to keep clicking for the bullet to move. Am I doing something wrong? Is anyone able to help me with this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Should'nt the if statement become a while statement?

Comment: @DaviBertolli I tried that as well. It completely crashed my program.

Answer (score 0):

When clicking, you want to make your tank only 'spawn' a bullet, and then the bullet should update seperately from the tank to travel it's own.

This works best if there's a `Bullet` class.

With classes, you can create multiple instances of the same object. And in your case, create multiple bullets. 
Even if you only are going to use one bullet at a time, classes will help keeping the code related to the bullet in one place.

I recommend searching up how classes work in C#, as they're very common to use, but a little big to explain. It'll really help a lot to use classes if you're working with objects that can appear multiple times.

I'm gonna try to explain the basics though:

An object class in XNA/Monogame should have at least 3 functions: Create, Update and Draw.
For Create, I use the constructor to make the object. and define it the moment it needs to be created.

Update and Draw are similair and just need to be called for each existing object in the Update and Draw methods in the main class (usually game1.cs), this is why I use a list so they can go through each object in the list easily. Objects that are no longer needed (for example, they reach out of bounds and keep flying in the abyss indefenitely) should be deleted to keep the performance in check.

Bullet.cs class:

```
int x;
int y;
Texture2D texture;

public Bullet(int tempx, int tempy)
{
    //these values below will be defined when you create a new bullet 
    x = tempx;
    y = tempy;
}

public Update()
{
    //this will move(update) the bullet seperately
    //place your bullet update logic here
    speed.Y = bulletDirY * (bulletSpeed * (float)(gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds));

        bulletPos.Y = bulletPos.Y - speed.Y;
        bulletRec.Y = (int)bulletPos.Y;

    //also place here the code that checks and delete the bullet if it's no longer needed.
}


public Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    //draws the bullet
    spriteBatch.Draw(/*texture, position and color*/);

}
```

game1 class:

```
//place this on top of the page, this list will keep track of every bullet created in the session.
List<Bullet> bullets = new List<Bullets>();

//place this in the update class
foreach (Bullet b in bullets)
{
    b.Update();
}

//place this in the draw class
foreach (Bullet b in bullets)
{
    b.Draw(spriteBatch);
}
```

The class where you shoot your bullet:

```
private void tankShoot(GameTime gameTime)
{
    if (mouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && prevMouse.LeftButton != ButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        //create the bullet
        bullets.Add(new Bullet(/*define spawn locations ect.*/));
    }
}
```